# Use mutate to add a new key whose relation is in another table. Tidyverse/Lubridate/R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataframe with monitorings of some variables and each register is associated with a key1. However, I want to relate this variables with others which are associated with a different new key2. To do so, I have a table which shows the relation between both keys.

This is simple, I guess I only need to create a new column adding the new key2 to the dataframe with mutate(), but the tricky part is that more than one value of key2 can be related with the same key1. Because key1 means customers, and key2 means events. Luckely, the table with shows dependencies of both key1 and key2, shows a range of time as well. So I could be able to distinguish which key2 I have to mutate in my dataframe using the time of the registers and the intervals of the events. I don't know how to do it though.

I provide here a simpler example, 12 samples of register associated with 3 customers (01,02,03), which corresponds to 4 events (A,B,C,D).

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(
  Key1 = c('01','01','01','02','02','02','02','02','02','03','03','03'),
  type = c('R','R','R','C','C','R','C','R','R','C','C','R'),
  value = dnorm(1:12,mean=5,sd=10),
  hour = c(now(),now()+hours(1),now()+hours(2),now()-hours(338),now()-hours(337),
           now()-hours(336), now()-hours(48),now()-hours(47),now()-hours(46),
           now(),now()+hours(20),now()+hours(30))
  )

df2 <- data.frame(
  key2 = c('A','B','C','D'),
  Key1 = c('02','02','01','03'),
  time = c(interval(now()-hours(340),now()-hours(299)),
                    interval(now()-hours(60),now()-hours(46)),
                    interval(now()-hours(10),now()+hours(10)),
                    interval(now()-hours(5),now()+hours(50))))
)
```

I would like to know if there's a way to create a new column adding the key2 of the event which the hour of the register lies in for every sample in df1. I know how to do it with a for loop, but I want to learn a way to do it with tydyverse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_wider(values_from = time,
                                names_from = c(key2)),
            by = "Key1") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = df2$key2,
               values_to = "values_df2",
               names_to = "key2") %>%
  filter(!is.na(values_df2) & hour %within% values_df2)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Key1  type   value hour                key2  values_df2                                        
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dttm>              <chr> <Interval>                                        
 1 01    R     0.0368 2021-10-25 11:34:35 C     2021-10-25 01:34:38 CEST--2021-10-25 21:34:38 CEST
 2 01    R     0.0381 2021-10-25 12:34:35 C     2021-10-25 01:34:38 CEST--2021-10-25 21:34:38 CEST
 3 01    R     0.0391 2021-10-25 13:34:35 C     2021-10-25 01:34:38 CEST--2021-10-25 21:34:38 CEST
 4 02    C     0.0397 2021-10-11 09:34:35 A     2021-10-11 07:34:38 CEST--2021-10-13 00:34:38 CEST
 5 02    C     0.0399 2021-10-11 10:34:35 A     2021-10-11 07:34:38 CEST--2021-10-13 00:34:38 CEST
 6 02    R     0.0397 2021-10-11 11:34:35 A     2021-10-11 07:34:38 CEST--2021-10-13 00:34:38 CEST
 7 02    C     0.0391 2021-10-23 11:34:35 B     2021-10-22 23:34:38 CEST--2021-10-23 13:34:38 CEST
 8 02    R     0.0381 2021-10-23 12:34:35 B     2021-10-22 23:34:38 CEST--2021-10-23 13:34:38 CEST
 9 02    R     0.0368 2021-10-23 13:34:35 B     2021-10-22 23:34:38 CEST--2021-10-23 13:34:38 CEST
10 03    C     0.0352 2021-10-25 11:34:35 D     2021-10-25 06:34:38 CEST--2021-10-27 13:34:38 CEST
11 03    C     0.0333 2021-10-26 07:34:35 D     2021-10-25 06:34:38 CEST--2021-10-27 13:34:38 CEST
12 03    R     0.0312 2021-10-26 17:34:35 D     2021-10-25 06:34:38 CEST--2021-10-27 13:34:38 CEST
```

Obviously, if you only need to add the key, you can get rid of the last column by `select(-values_df2)`, which then gives:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Key1  type   value hour                key2 
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>
 1 01    R     0.0368 2021-10-25 11:34:35 C    
 2 01    R     0.0381 2021-10-25 12:34:35 C    
 3 01    R     0.0391 2021-10-25 13:34:35 C    
 4 02    C     0.0397 2021-10-11 09:34:35 A    
 5 02    C     0.0399 2021-10-11 10:34:35 A    
 6 02    R     0.0397 2021-10-11 11:34:35 A    
 7 02    C     0.0391 2021-10-23 11:34:35 B    
 8 02    R     0.0381 2021-10-23 12:34:35 B    
 9 02    R     0.0368 2021-10-23 13:34:35 B    
10 03    C     0.0352 2021-10-25 11:34:35 D    
11 03    C     0.0333 2021-10-26 07:34:35 D    
12 03    R     0.0312 2021-10-26 17:34:35 D
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome! Please, could you tell me why you say to pivot_longer "cols = !!df2$key2,"? 

This is exactly what I was asking, however using this code with my real dataframes, I lose some samples, while using for loops I don't lose any sample with the last filtering (ofc using for loops is more more expensive).

I don't understand how is this possible, your code looks really good but it's something wrong that the example I provided doesn't show.

Comment: Right, I actually don't need `!!df2$key2`, `df2$key2` is totally sufficient. As for the rows where you get a difference - it's impossible to tell why that is unless you share an example of that data. So I suggest you try to narrow down your data to some of these missing rows and then provide the data here with `dput` and then we can check what's the difference and how the code needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I'm trying to guess why is that happening. My first idea is pivot_wider and pivot_longer end in some rows without any match with the key2 so filtering the NA eliminate them. But that is not happening, at least with pivot_wider. 

I'll have a look, I won't provide my real data, at least for now because then I would have to anonymise it and it'll be a pain.

Anyway, with your code I learnt a good way to relation different tables in one using pivot functions and I really appreaciate it. You have my green tick to your solution! Still not knowing why you say col=df2$key2 though.

Comment: But is it really that difficult to provide the data in the structure as above just with some different values for the keys? I mean it's just dates, so really nothing confidential. Would be curious to see these example (one or two will do the trick) to provide a proper solution. as for `col = df2$key2`: if you check how the data looks after the `left_join` step, you'll see 4 columns, A, B, C, D and I want to pivot_longer these. Since A, B, C, D are exactly the values form df2$key2, I just use this to select the columns to reshape. I could also have used a different tidy select helper.

Comment: Ok, I got the problem! Some samples have the hour time value outside the intervals so filter eliminates them. That's not a problem at all, because i dont want them and otherwise I could change the interval for the keys. I didn't know about using this method for selecting the columns. Relly helpful! Thanks a lot!